# Can't remove UPnP port mapping

Tags: upnp

I was messing around with a UPnP library which I'll be using for a game server. I came to a point where I had to make my addPortMapping-function fail somehow, but since I don't have direct access to the router, I can't turn off UPnP in order to make it fail.

What I did try, in order to make the function fail (which ultimately it **didn't**), was to try to add a port mapping to port -1.

Now I have the problem of not being able to remove a port mapping from the router to my computer on port -1... 
As ports can't be < 1, this confuses me.

Is this a known problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you want it to fail for testing purposes? If so, how are you testing? Unit tests, integration tests, user tests? And what testing tools do you use?

Comment: @stonedsquirrel As I've pointed out, the problem is that I can't remove that port mapping from externalIP:-1 to internalIP:-1.

Comment: Yes but WHY do you want to remove the port mapping so that your library call fails? There might be other ways to achieve the same. Describe what you want to achieve ulitmatly. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WANIPConnection:2 specification defines both externalPort and internalPort as "ui2" so they're unsigned integers 0-65535 (internalPort also can't be 0, which is used as wildcard for externalPort). If an implementation accepts -1 it's just broken: So this is not a known problem but a bug in your router. Buggy UPnP-IGD routers in general *are* a known problem so this is not a surprise.